# Type dll exists in both locations

Tags: asp.net

When I tried to publish a web site, I got the following error message.

What does it mean and what's the solution?

Thanks

The type 'Controls_WUCVehicleDetails' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\online\4d2b861a\e9151913\App_Web_vjqwyepz.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\online\4d2b861a\e9151913\App_Web_3cfshxzl.dll'    D:\SVN\OASYS\trunk\Websites\OnLine\ContractEntry_RAC.aspx

Comment: look at this answer if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852039/compilation-error-the-type-asp-global-asax-exists-in-both-dlls

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 2 aspx pages which are having the same name in their inherits= in the <@page language=......inherits=> line at the top of the class.

Changing the inherits= name may solves the error.

Refference :-

[ASP.Net error: "The type 'foo' exists in both "temp1.dll" and "temp2.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll)