# ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net

I'm a beginner in ASP.Net WebForms.I have a problem when I run my application.

This is my compilation error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.global_asax' exists in
>   both 'c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\7b316ac0\74a3eae4\App_global.asax.nlr3yglh.dll' and
>   'c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\7b316ac0\74a3eae4\assembly\dl3\c7339aea\6d83affb_aa85d001\App_global.asax.DLL'

Source Error:

```
Line 165:        }
Line 166:        
Line 167:        protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
Line 168:            get {
Line 169:                return ((ASP.global_asax)(this.Context.ApplicationInstance));
```

Source File: c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7b316ac0\74a3eae4\App_Web_userlogin.ascx.cdcab7d2.wpz3jgra.0.cs    Line: 167

Comment: where is your source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation Error : The type 'ASP.global\_asax' exists in both dlls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852039/compilation-error-the-type-asp-global-asax-exists-in-both-dlls)

Comment: Check that you don't have 2 files named global.asax. If you don't, try the steps in the above link.

Comment: this is my bin folder

Comment: I'm trying to remove App_global.asax.dll from my Folder bin But when I rerun my application I find it again .What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use the option of building assemblies for every page. You should build into a single assembly. If you use assemblies per page, when you deploy you should delete all assemblies in the bin, since they are previous versions and they have unique ids in the name, so they don't get overwritten.

In your case, clean your bin and then build. But I would suggest a single library for a full code-behind update, rather then specific code-behind updates for specific pages.

Comment: I have a huge project and I have many assemblies for each page