# ASAP.global_asax exists in both directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

I have a problem with my ASP.NET site. I get the error below. I have located both files and when I delete or hide them. I get another error saying the files could not be found. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852039/compilation-error-the-type-asp-global-asax-exists-in-both-dlls) but none of ALL the solutions seem to solve the problem.

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.global_asax' exists in
>   both 'c:\Users\sindi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0480ec42\5940d271\App_global.asax.kndzjhmx.dll' and
>   'c:\Users\sindi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0480ec42\5940d271\assembly\dl3\144db4ab\e992b420_111cd301\Synergince.DLL'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 166:        } Line 167:         Line 168:        protected
>   ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance { Line 169:            get { Line
>   170:                return
>   ((ASP.global_asax)(this.Context.ApplicationInstance));

Comment: Try going here `c:\Users\sindi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET` and delete all the folders in there

Comment: I deleted them. Restarted visual studio. Cleaned the solution and built it again. But the problem still persists