# Which options are the most performance way of publishing asp.net website project - deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment, publishing, vs-web-site-project

I am asking in terms of performance

**Which would run fastest on the server (windows server 2012 r2 - 24 cores - 64 gb ram) - serving pages fastest way - reducing load times**

Asp.net website project , c# , .net 4.5 , visual studio 2013 update 3

*I don't need site to be updated-able*

*I don't care how many or how big files to be deployed*

Here the options available

[image]

Comment: This isn't really "to broad" because there is a single, specific answer that is reasonably upvoted.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What effect does the new precompile during publishing option have on MVC4 applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179519/what-effect-does-the-new-precompile-during-publishing-option-have-on-mvc4-applic)

Answer (score 21):

From my understanding:

- **Delete all existing files prior to publishing** will prevent old/stale files from previous publish runs from hanging around.  Saves some disk space and keeps things clean.  No significant performance impact (unless you start to run out of disk space).
- **Precompile during publishing** is probably the largest performance gain.  If not checked, code backing your pages/views will be compiled when first hit, causing a delay for the first user to hit each page.
- **Allow precompiled site to be updatable**. Without setting this checkbox, pages and user controls (.aspx, .ascx, and .master files) are copied as-is to the target folder and can be updated as text files without recompiling the project. Otherwise, the HTML markup for pages and user controls is removed and compiled into the assembly output. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx  This would likely cause a very minor performance hit, as the additional files must be opened and processed.
- **Merge options** Merging files into a single assembly would result in the least number of separate files to be processed at runtime.  I have not found documentation on the performance impact, but I suspect a single assembly would allow for a minor performance improvement.

Comment: thanks for answer. so it seems like: delete all existing files mark, precompile mark, allow updatedable unmark, merge all outputs into single mark right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do